# Get result between 1-50 python using math

Tags: python, django, numpy, math

I want results between 1-50 using python mathematically.

My code has a string of different characters every time.

I have to take a length and do some math so that results always comes between 1-50.

Currently, I am doing the same but only for 1-10.

my code looks like below:-

```
ans= 0
sum = 0
char=update1['headline']  # this is dynamic random char string 
sum=len(char)
ans= (sum % 10) + 1
print(ans)
```

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Why is this a question? Seems like the question was modified today as the earlier answer seems to answer a different question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `ans= (sum % 10) + 1` to `ans= (sum % 50) + 1`

Answer (score 0):

Use **HTTP Request activity** for this

```
Package: UiPath.WebAPI.Activity
Activity: UiPath.WebAPI.Activities.HttpClient
```

https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/http-client